# In R, transform a vector with repeated values to a vector of single ordered values including the repetitions?

Tags: r

I have a vector `x <- c(5, 5, 5, 3, 2, 2, 5, 5, 2)`. I need to get a new vector with the ordered distinct (but duplicates allowed) values:
`y <- c(5, 3, 2, 5, 2)`

I'm sure it's a trivial problem but I've been looking around and I don't see a simple way to do it.

Comment: You could try `rle(x)`

Comment: Thanks a lot Vincent. It was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just out of the curiosity, I've tried to solve it without `rle(x)$values`:

```
x[x != c(x[-1], Inf)]
# [1] 5 3 2 5 2
```

Basically we are just comparing the original vector, and its' *shifted* to the left version, to create a *subset* index. So if the *current* element **is equal** to the *next* element, we return `FALSE` to remove this element from the initial vector.

```
555322552
|||||||||
55322552i
|||||||||
001101011
|||||||||
xx53x2x52

result: 53252
```

We always return the last element (hopefully, there are no `NA`s or `NULL`s).